# How can I simplify $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}3k+1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, products

I've found that I can simplify $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}2k-1$ to $\frac{(2\cdot n)!}{2^n\cdot n!}$, for example:

$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{4}2k-1=1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8}=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8}{(1\cdot2)\cdot(2\cdot2)\cdot(3\cdot2)\cdot(4\cdot2)}=\frac{(2\cdot4)!}{4!\cdot2^4}$

I'm having difficulties applying the same tricks on $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}3k+1$.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: $\prod_{k=1}^4 2k-1 = ( \prod_{k=1}^4 2k ) - 1 ≠ \prod_{k=1}^4 (2k-1)$.

Comment: As for 'simplifying' the product you want, it's not possible to do it in the same way.

Comment: @user21820: Thank you. Can you prove that this is not possible? Is there a different simplification method that you might know of?

Comment: I don't know how to prove that it is impossible, which is why I didn't post an answer.

Comment: The product can be expressed in terms of the gamma function. Are you interested in those expressions, too, or only in those which use basic arithmetic and factorials?

Comment: @ReinhardMeier: I got the "gamma" alternate form by running this on WolframAlpha. I was hoping to find something which doesn't make use of this function.